# I use cloudinary_gem 1.5.2 ,throw error "undefined method `http_code' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method `code' for nil:NilClass>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can upload image to cloudinary.but throw error

```
undefined method `http_code' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method `code' for nil:NilClass>".
```

Then I update gem cloudinary version to 1.13.1,It's not a problem or not solved. Throw the same exception.

**Here is my code**

```
result = params[:image].collect do |image|
  Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(image, options)
end
```

**Here is my error message**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAw1p.png)

**My ruby version is 2.3.2
My rails version is5.0.3**

Comment: did you tried to add:  require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

Comment: @Nezir I add require 'net/http' , but the errors is the same